# preg_match doesn't accept new lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I know it sounds a little strange, but I'll try to explain.
use this code to check if `$text` contains unsupported characters:

```
if(!preg_match('/\A[\w .,]+\z/', $text))
{
    echo "Text contains unsupported characters.";
}
```

Now the problem is that `$text` is the text entered by the user in textarea.

```
$text_c = $_POST['text'];
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text_c);
echo "<form method='post'><textarea name='text'>".$text."</textarea><br /><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
```

Everything works perfectly, except one thing. Example, if this is text entered in textarea:

> Hello, my name is John.

OK.

> Hello, my name is John.
>   I am 20 years old.

NO. Text contains unsupported characters. (refers to the new line, because content of the textarea change and have something like: `My name is John.\r\nI am 20 years old.`)

My question is: what I need to change to support new lines? I hope you understand.

**EDIT:** I just discovered, without `mysql_real_escape_string` everything works exactly as I want. Is there any solution to "combine" `mysql_real_escape_string` with `preg_match` (in my case) or `mysql_real_escape_string` supposed to drop?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is supposed to be used for SQL strings, not for HTML output; use `htmlspecialchars` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\s` to represent whitespace (new lines, tabs and spaces).

So your regex becomes: `/\A[\w .,\s]+\z/`

Note `\n` `\r` are both valid escape characters and `\r\n` together will match a dos line break if you don't want to include spaces/tabs.

Good reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Same error. Returns the text in textarea with `\r\n` and says it contains unsupported characters.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same error; rather, it's not erroring for the same reason you think it is. 
It's not the newlines that are tripping your regex up, it's the numbers. ;-) 
Add \d to your regex as well: `/\A[\w\d\s.,]+\z/`

Comment: `\w` matches digits as well as letters, so adding `\d` won't make any difference.